# XPages Standby control breaks Scrolling in Bootstrap

Tags: xpages

I have an XPages Bootstrap based application where some functions take a little time to process so I've added the OpenNTF Standby control (https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=standby-dialog-custom-control) to the page to show an indicator during the Partial refresh.

Since dropping the control on the page after the partial refresh runs it seems to break the page's ability to scroll.  I can scroll before the partial refresh but not after.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: David, I have seen the same with OneUI. I ended up removing the standby control.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're getting a global JavaScript error (I'm curious as to the stack trace from your browser's console), which prevents further execution. While *in development only* (aka- don't force error handling like below), you could try adding a script early on to try and catch the culprit, you could try and load up a script, as early as possible, to force handling of the error to `return true` or, more importantly, dump out more information on what is throwing the error.

For more on the global error event handler, here's [a link to the corresponding page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror).

```javascript
function ignoreError(msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
    var string = msg.toLowerCase();
    var substring = "script error";
    if (string.indexOf(substring) > -1){
        alert('Script Error: See Browser Console for Detail');
    } else {
        var message = [
            'Message: ' + msg,
            'URL: ' + url,
            'Line: ' + lineNo,
            'Column: ' + columnNo,
            'Error object: ' + JSON.stringify(error)
        ].join(' - ');

        alert(message);
    }

    return true; // normally, such a global exception ought to return false
}
window.onerror=ignoreError();
```